# Where did the initial t come from in tante?

Tags: étymologie

I've looked up the etymology of *tante*, but it just says it comes from Old French *ante* without saying how it gained the initial "t".

Where did this "t" come from?

See

- ["tante" on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tante#French),
- [Etymologie de TANTE](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/tante) on CNTRL.fr.

Comment: Good question. Pure speculation: This is one of the words that children will learn and use frequently. Such words are highly prone to [reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#Reduplicative_babbling_in_child_language_acquisition). Perhaps the final /t/ migrated backwards so that *tante* would be more like *maman*, *papa*, *bobo*, *dodo*, etc. Another direction to take it would be something related to a common epenthesis or liaison, though what would be specific to *tante* doesn't come to mind.

Comment: @Luke. The *tata/tatie* reduplications may be indeed be linked to this added *t*. Now, why would *tonton* be used for uncle?

Comment: @Stéphane Possibly for a reason I considered touching on above: When French does pull a consonant out of nowhere, it tends to be /t/. (At least, so I seem to remember learning as an undergrad. Consider *icitte*.) And why pull one out of nowhere at all in this case? Perhaps to fill the onset; CV is an early-acquired and compelling syllable pattern. Alternatively I suppose the *ta tante* below also suggests *ton oncle*, but it feels somewhat arbitrary to me. (Why not "ma/mon"?)

Answer (score 5):

The [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/tante) has this hypothesis, ***ta ante*** has agglutinated in ***tante*** which would have turn into a noun.

It gives some examples in Walloon with which *monfré* is brother and *mononk* is uncle.

I found:  *kimin s' poitt voss **monfrér** ?* = *Comment se porte votre **frère** ?*

A similar agglutination exists with *monsieur* where *mon* has lost its adjectival status: *ton monsieur*, *mon bon monsieur* are possible.

Comment: There's also *madame*, and Quebec french has *mononcle* and *matante*.

Comment: @Circeus Yes, and *mademoiselle* too but while *ton monsieur* is is grammatical while *ta madame* is only spoken French. *Qui est ta matante préférée ?* :-) https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/matante-mononcle-dictionnaire-quebecois/

Comment: In Brussels dialect too, you can find "tetante" and "menonk"

Comment: "menonk"? That sounds practically Dutch. :-:P

The Petit Robert also says it comes from *ta ante*.